# Word Interop Batch Printing

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have an application that creates multiple (regularly 1000+) Word files and then prints them.

I have created the below code that, once the PrintDialog is Ok'd proceeds to print the documents that reside in a folder.  However recently we've had some strange behaviour following some Office updates (its Office 2010, which we cannot upgrade).  The screen literally flickers, like a really bad graphics problem, then Word crashes after about 500 prints.  This hasn't happened before and has been running for probably 12 months+ without issue.

As you can see, the application opens one instance of Word, then uses that to open>print>close each document.  I can't see how this causes a problem, as Word only ever has one document open at a time.  The memory size of winword.exe also doesn't increase significantly beyond the size of when its first opened too, so the Office updates don't initially appear to have introduced a memory leak.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

```
if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
                    int c = 1;
                    int total = directoryInfo.GetFiles().Count();
                    // Set the Progress bar details
                    App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate { MainWindow.ui_progressBar.Maximum = directoryInfo.GetFiles().Length; });
                    // loop through the files in order
                    foreach (FileInfo report in directoryInfo.GetFiles().OrderBy(x => x.FullName))
                    {
                        UpdateUI("Printing " + c.ToString() + " / " + total.ToString());
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document reportFile = wordApp.Documents.Add(report.FullName);
                        wordApp.ActivePrinter = printDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
                        wordApp.ActiveDocument.PrintOut();
                        reportFile.Close(SaveChanges: false);
                        reportFile = null;
                        PrinterCounter++;
                        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate { MainWindow.ui_progressBar.Value = PrinterCounter; });
                        c++;
                    }
}
```

Comment: This reminds of issues I had batch processing emails in outlook.  It would not be stable yet not predictable.  I ended up adding a sleep of.5s after each mail.

Comment: That's interesting, and possibly a nice quick fix.  I'll give it a try, but won't be until Monday.

Comment: Where and how do you run the code? Did you try to run the GC to swipe the heap at some point? Do you get any exceptions in the code?

Comment: We get a COM exception, but mainly its Word that crashes.  My app moves on to the next stage of archiving the print run and tidying up a few db tables.  I'm not quite sure what you mean by run the GC to swipe at the heap?